c++ timer in kernel background
I have a user-space program that implements a simple timer function using a thread to count down for 24 hours
const int SECONDS_IN_24_HOURS = 24 * 60 * 60;

DWORD WINAPI TimerThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SECONDS_IN_24_HOURS; ++i)
    {
        double currentTime = MyTimer(); 
        std::cout << "Thread " << GetCurrentThreadId() << " countdown at: " << i + 1 << " seconds, Current time: " << currentTime << " seconds\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    std::cout << "---------------- 24 hours have passed! ----------------\n";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThreadId;

    // Create a thread to run the timer function
    hThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // default stack size
        TimerThreadFunction,    // thread function
        NULL,                   // parameter to thread function
        0,                      // default creation flags
        &dwThreadId             // returns the thread identifier
    );

    if (hThread == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Thread created successfully with ID: " << dwThreadId << std::endl;

   
    SetThreadAffinityMask(hThread, 1 << 0);


    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);


    CloseHandle(hThread);


    return 0;
}

i need to transfer it to kernel space the timer should be running in background how i can do that ?

Have you tried to test this with a chronograph in hand? I'm afraid it won't really work that well. And another question, why the wild mix netween winapi anc c++ standard library? You know, the latter has a nice simple thread abstraction that works beautifully with C++.

Have a look at the Task Scheduler API
